# Is it wrong to post answers that uses eval?

Tags: discussion, comments

Is it wrong to post answers that uses eval()?

Comment: I think that your meta question is missing key context that is needed to fully understand your problem and be able to answer it.

Comment: It's not wrong, it's dangerous.

Comment: Even if the program doesn't contain inputs?

Comment: @Dharman indeed in most cases suggesting to use `eval` in both JavaScript and Python (or any other form of runtime code parsing/execution) is a wrong answer...   But it is not wrong to post wrong answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there’s nothing against site or network rules in suggesting `eval()` in answers. Site rules do not dictate content; they dictate processes. The site rules only require that answers attempt to answer what’s in the question, not what the answers should contain.

And, by those lights, answers suggesting `eval()` are still *answers*. They may be *bad* answers that expose readers who follow the advice to serious security risks¹, and therefore such answers may attract downvotes and criticism (which is *precisely* the purpose of downvotes: to warn or recommend against specific answers), but they’re answers nonetheless.

So go ahead, so long as you’re willing to accept the inevitable downvotes and critical comments.

---

¹: <sub>It might be nice if `eval()`-suggesting answers clearly and unambiguously communicated these security risks, but again, there’s no rule saying you must; but it would provide some level of defense against the downvotes.</sub>

Comment: @AnnZen If you don’t already know what the security risks are for `eval()`, that’s your problem right there.

Comment: @AnnZen What research have you done about what problems eval might have? (Rhetorical.) (Such research was called for before posting your question here.)

Comment: OP is asking precisely because they are aware of the risks but they see it in answers

Comment: @medic17 Meta is not the place to provide technical content. If OP wants to ask about the security risks of `eval()`, she should do so on Main. But the point is it is *OP* who is recommending `eval()`, as a solution, and the people asking questions she’s answering on SO are relying on *her* to have the appropriate technical expertise; it is her duty to ensure she provides all the relevant information in her answers. And no, OP is *not* “asking precisely because they are aware of the risks”: in comments, now deleted, it was clear that OP was *completely unaware* of said risks.